# Angular, refresh source

Tags: angularjs, unix, logging

I'm having a trouble looking for an answer for this situation.

Our system server has logs that keeps updating.
The view of the logs is terrible ! and very messy.
So I want to build a web application that will show the logs and will offer filtering options to make our life easier :).

So this is what I've planned:
1) I'll load up to 50 log lines (so it wont be blank when opened);
2) I'll keep pulling information for every line the console write.

Well, How do I approach step 2?  how can I be synced with the server logs?

furthermore, When I load the 50 lines maybe a new line alrdy had been put out in the console, which lower the integrity of data provided in the log viewer.

BTW I use PuTTY to see the log console.

Excuse me for my bad English. Thanks from advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you are planning on doing this entirely client side with Angular, you're going to need to:

- Create an API, some endpoint/url that you can fetch your logs from. Something like `http://www.example.com/my-console-feed/`. You might already have this.
- Poll the server with angular's `$interval` at the interval of your choosing.

If you were operating with web sockets, perhaps some continuous feed could be done.

So you could make a factory that looks something like this:

```
(function() {

  'use strict';


  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .factory('pollingFactory', pollingFactory);


  function pollingFactory($http, $interval) {
    return function() {

      // 60000 is 1 minute
      var duration = 60000;

      // log API endpoint
      var myLogAPIEndpoint = 'http://www.example.com/my-console-feed/';

      // this will hit the API every minute
      $interval(function() {

        // poll the api for new logs
        $http({
          url: myLogAPIEndpoint,
          method: 'GET'
        })
       .success(function(response) {
         // do something with the response
       })

      }, duration); 

    }
  }


})();
```

If you were going to go this way, I'd use $q as a promise library and in your controller, when the promise resolves, update the model in your scope with the new logs. If you're using `ng-repeat`, I'd also recommend using `track by` for performance if the logs have unique IDs.

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeGertrudes/bu3aj4vz/3/) polling an API every 3 seconds.

Comment: I'm pretty much looking for a 'less'  command  that is available in unix,  in angular.  So when the angular will load the file,  it will automatically keep it updated for each row he gets.

Comment: You might want to shift your concerns from Angular and focus on WebSocket technology like socket.io. http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/